# Postgres 9.5 server not starting due to already active replication slot

Tags: postgresql, database-replication, postgresql-replication

I have a Postgres (version - 9.5 Beta) server replication set up where there are 3 slaves and a primary server. After all required configuration is done, I start 1st slave after taking base backup and it gets started. As I start 2nd slave, it does not start. Here is the log that I get repeatedly -

**FATAL:  could not start WAL streaming: ERROR:  replication slot "abcdef" is already active for PID 5368**

The same happens on trying to start 3rd slave. Server won't start giving same logs.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you've set `primary_slot_name` to the same slot in all three replicas.

Each replica must use a different replication slot in [`recovery.conf`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/recovery-config.html) if you're going to use replication slots for streaming replication. Use of a replication slot is not required if you're using streaming replication with WAL archive based fallback.

Comment: Thanks. It works now. But now on querying SELECT * from pg_replication_slots;, the replication slot assigned to 1st slave shows inactive (f in active column). Any thoughts? @Craig

Comment: It could see logs like requested WAL segment 000000010000000000000017 has already been removed in slave whose replication slot is inactive. Is it because of that? Will I need to take basebackup again? @Craig